# Can't understand why I'm getting a 'String index out of range: -3' error - Java

Tags: java, string, text, indexing, range

I have a Java program reading from a text file, and I'm trying to set a variable to the String between two strings - between   "text" : "  and   " , "date    . I keep getting the error 'String index out of range: -3', and I can't seem to find any other solutions which I can apply to my code.

```
String filename5 = "C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\Tests\\wunderground
\\outputTweetsWeatherAlerts.txt";
String filename6 = filename5;

FileInputStream input_file5 = new FileInputStream(filename5);
Scanner input5 = new Scanner(input_file5);
input5.findInLine("\"id\"");
String tweetText1 = input5.next();
int startPosition = tweetText1.indexOf(": \"") + ": \"".length();  
System.out.println("Start Position: " + startPosition);

int endPosition = tweetText1.indexOf("\" , \"date", startPosition);  
System.out.println("endPosition " + endPosition);

String tweetText = tweetText1.substring(startPosition, endPosition); 
// THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR:   String index out of range: -3
System.out.println(tweetText);
```

The text file I'm reading is as follows:

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507dc77633f77fd20f7eec96"} , "id" : 258307760112955393 , "text" : "Some random text" , "date" : { "$date" : ... }

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you definitely need to use a genuine JSON parser

Comment: Are you sure "date" is actually on the next line - it's on the next line visibly, but is there a line break.

Comment: Try printing out the results of each statement so you can confirm the results.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (or at least doesn't throw an error) which suggests that `findInLine()` (which you haven't shown us) is not returning what you think it should be returning.

As Philip Whitehouse suggests in the comments, maybe your line of text is actually split over two lines?

You need to print out the results at each step to see what is going wrong, or use a debugger to examine the variables.

```
    String tweetText1 = "{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"507dc77633f77fd20f7eec96\"} , \"id\" : 258307760112955393 , \"text\" : \"Some random text\" , \"date\" : { \"$date\" : ... }";
    int startPosition = tweetText1.indexOf(": \"") + ": \"".length();
    System.out.println(startPosition);
    int endPosition = tweetText1.indexOf("\" , \"date", startPosition);
    System.out.println(endPosition);

    String tweetText = tweetText1.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
    // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR: String index out of range: -3
    System.out.println(tweetText);
```

This outputs:

```
start
22
105
507dc77633f77fd20f7eec96"} , "id" : 258307760112955393 , "text" : "Some random text
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

I changed the code slightly, but still get the same error message, regardless of if I use .next() or .nextLine() ?

This is my output:

Start Position: 2
endPosition -1
String index out of range: -3

I've edited the post to include more code from above. The line I'm trying to read from in the text file is on the second line, and all the string I'm trying to search in is on one line - I thought by putting the 'input5.findInLine("\"text\"");'   in, then I would skip to that line anyway?

Totally confused!?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, you are probably using Scanner incorrectly. Try printing out tweetText1 and it'll give you an empty string. What you could probably do is to retain the FileInputStream, get the contents of the file and put into a String by using a recursive fis.read and adding the char in a StringBuilder (as an example) then use @DNA 's code.

OR the best alternative I can think of is to use `input5.nextLine()` instead of `input5.next()`, that'll do the trick given that the data is in one line ONLY. If it's multiple lines then that won't work either.